# Conditional statement is not working in json schema validation

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a json response like below..

```
[{

        "views": [{             
                "groups": [{
                        "type": "static",                       
                        "tiles": [{
                                "context": "event",
                                "collection": "selo",
                                "tile_type": "static"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, {                
                "groups": [{
                        "type": "static",                       
                        "tiles": [{
                                "context": "event",
                                "collection": "nitic",                              
                                "tile_type": "static"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, {                
                "groups": [{
                        "type": "scrollable",                       
                        "tiles": [{
                                "name": "loca",
                                "location": "cal",                              
                                "tile_type": "person"
                            }, {
                                "name": "tom",
                                "location": "toc",                              
                                "tile_type": "person"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here I have to validate the `tile` objects inside every `group` array.Based on the `type` key in the `group` object the size and key elements in the `tile`
object varies. For isntance if the `type` key is `static` the size of the `tile` object is `1` and if it is value is `scrollable` it contians more than one
`tile` items.In addition to this the `tile` elemnts also different.

for `static` tile i have to verify the existence of following key elemnts

```
                          "context"
                        "collection"                            
                        "tile_type"
```

for `scrollable` tile i have to verify the existence of following key elemnts

```
                        "name"
                        "location"
                        "tile_type"
```

Based on these i have defined a schema using switch like this and the schema validation is not working.Instead of `switch` keyword i tried with `anyOf` as well.(Iam using the draft7 version)

schema definition

```
   "switch": [
                    {
                      "if": {
                        "properties": {
                          "tile_type": {
                            "enum": [
                              "static"
                            ]
                          }

                        },
                        "required": [
                          "context",
                          "collection",
                          "tile_type"
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "if": {
                        "properties": {
                          "tile_type": {
                            "enum": [
                              "person"
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        "required": [
                          "name",
                          "location",
                          "tile_type"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
```

Tried with anyOF

```
"anyOf": [{
        "properties": {
            "tile_type": {
                "enum": [
                    "static"
                ]
            }

        },
        "required": [
            "context",
            "collection",
            "tile_type"
        ]

    }, {

        "properties": {
            "tile_type": {
                "enum": [
                    "person"
                ]
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "name",
            "location",
            "tile_type"
        ]

    }
]
```

Errors oberseved while using anyOf

```
 Found 2 error(s)
Message:
Required properties are missing from object: context, collection.
Schema path:
http://example.com/root.json#/views/groups/tiles/items/required
Message:
Required properties are missing from object: context, collection.
Schema path:
http://example.com/root.json#/views/groups/tiles/items/required
```

Tried in :https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Any solution to perform this?

**Updated part goes below**

In the response sometimes the some of the `tile` data contains the keys `errorText` and `errorCode` .

[{

```
    "views": [{             
            "groups": [{
                    "type": "static",                       
                    "tiles": [{
                            "context": "event",                              
                            "tile_type": "static"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, {                
            "groups": [{
                    "type": "static",                       
                    "tiles": [{
                            "context": "event",
                            "collection": "nitic",                              
                            "tile_type": "static"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, {                
            "groups": [{
                    "type": "scrollable",                       
                    "tiles": [{
                            "name": "loca",
                            "location": "cal",                              
                            "tile_type": "person"
                        }, {

                            "errorText":"Tile failure",
                            "errorCode":1,                              
                            "tile_type": "person"
                        },
                              {

                            "errorText":"Tile not generated",
                            "errorCode":2,                              
                            "tile_type": "person"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

In such case I added an extra properties inside existing `oneOf` array as follows .
But it is not working.Whats wrong with my schema definition

```
 {
                    "properties": {
                      "type": {
                        "const": "scrollable"
                      },
                      "tiles": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "minItems": 2,
                        "items": {
                          "properties": {
                               "errorText": {
                              "const": ["Tile failure", "Tile not generated"]
                           }
                          },
                          "required": [
                            "errorText",
                            "errorCode",
                            "tile_type"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
```

error message while doing schema validations:

```
Message:
Value "static" does not match const.
Schema path:
#/items/properties/views/items/properties/groups/items/oneOf/2/properties/type/const
Message:
Value "static" does not match const.
Schema path:
#/items/properties/views/items/properties/groups/items/oneOf/1/properties/type/const
```

Comment: It is bad form to delete a question and re post it because it was locked and needed editing!! `switch` is not a JSON Schema key word.

Comment: Why i deleted that question is some one suggested to delete that post and was on hold state .Hence my question is not visible to anyone .That prompted me to delete that question and re posted here.

Comment: @Relequestual But i found lots of schema definitions using switch statements...https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/64

Comment: In my case instead of switch i tried with allOf,anyOne keywords it was not working

Comment: `switch` was proposed but never agreed, and we went for if/then/else in stead. I'm one of the JSON Schema core team, I know. `switch` is not in the spec, so any use of that keyword will be implementation specific.

Comment: In terms of using `Of` keywords, now you've provided what you've tried, I should be in a better position to help! Standby =]

Comment: The schema definitions you found were examples of how it could be used should it be included in the JSON Schema spec. It was a proposal. We opted not to allow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a schema which works for your given JSON instance with the following validation rules:

Type can be `static` or `scrollable`
If type is `static`, max one item in `tiles` array, and object properties must be `context`, `collection`, and `tile_type`.

If type is `scrollable`, at least two items in `tiles` array, and object properties must be `name`, `location`, and `tile_type`.

Items in a `scrollable` tile must be unique.

> In addition to this the tile elemnts also different

Sorry, this is not possible with JSON Schema.

---

Also tested using the same online validator you used.

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "properties": {
      "views": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "properties": {
            "groups": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "oneOf": [
                  {
                    "properties": {
                      "type": {
                        "const": "static"
                      },
                      "tiles": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "maxItems": 1,
                        "items": {
                          "propertyNames": {
                            "enum": [
                              "context",
                              "collection",
                              "tile_type"
                            ]
                          },
                          "required": [
                            "context",
                            "collection",
                            "tile_type"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "properties": {
                      "type": {
                        "const": "scrollable"
                      },
                      "tiles": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "minItems": 2,
                        "items": {
                          "propertyNames": {
                            "enum": [
                              "name",
                              "location",
                              "tile_type"
                            ]
                          },
                          "required": [
                            "name",
                            "location",
                            "tile_type"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This can be achieved with if/then/else, however using `oneOf` also works.

Comment: Happy to answer any questions you might have regarding this!

Comment: yea grt888...It is working......Thank you so much....i din't tried using this keyword "const"

Comment: due to this issue i was totally blocked for 1 week....Thanks once again for the the solution

Comment: You're welcome! `enum` with one item would have been valid also, `const` is a shortcut for that.

Comment: Happy to accept the bounty ;) - Also feel free to join the official JSON Schema slack server (link is on the website).

Comment: one more doubt.what does this propertyNames enum stands? why it is required? please reply if you dont mind?

Comment: Sure. `required` only checks the properties exist. If you were to set `additionalProperties: false`, it would fail validation because that schema doesn't use `properties`, so all properties are "additionalProperties". Using `propertyNames` makes sure the properties are ONLY those, and no additional properties are valid. You COULD add a definition for each property using `properties` and then use `additionalProperties: false`, but that's not what you want, and it's more verbose.

Comment: `Validation with "additionalProperties" applies only to the child
   values of instance names that do not match any names in "properties",
   and do not match any regular expression in "patternProperties".` - https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.6

Comment: Ok understood.. :-)

Comment: I have added on doubt in the above question.Could you please clarify this?

Comment: somehow i updated in your answer please neglect that